# Tag synonyms for Joomla

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Joomla has many different tags at the moment, but no tag synonyms. Questions tagged with [joomla1.6](/questions/tagged/joomla1.6), [joomla1.7](/questions/tagged/joomla1.7) and [joomla2.5](/questions/tagged/joomla2.5) for example could all go under the same tag, as they belong to the same Joomla series. E.g. questions tagged with only [joomla1.7](/questions/tagged/joomla1.7) don't have enough visibility at the moment, even though people interested in [joomla2.5](/questions/tagged/joomla2.5) could easily answer it, it's really the same Joomla edition.

Then again we have global Joomla tag, which most questions have, and most people see.

One suggestion is that we have one tag per Joomla series (for example, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 and 3.5 would be synonyms), so we don't dilute questions which are in the same scope (sorry for the poor phrasing).

Another suggestion is to make everything related to Joomla synonym with [joomla](/questions/tagged/joomla), so that all questions would have high visibility. People who answer Joomla questions are anyway likely to answer question for any release version. [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) is not broken into many tags per version, and I think it's a good thing

Answer (score 1):

**From strictly a logical point of view,** grouping the similar releases (like 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 and 3.5) makes perfect sense and in most of the cases a problem / question posted in 3.0 series will be relevant to the other releases as well) and may be easily found.

**From the practical point of view**, the `joomla` tag itself has more attention and more subscribers and the other tags all together. To express this in numbers:

- joomla tag - 1000 followers
- joomla 2.5 tag - 161 followers
- joomla 3.0 tag - 28 followers

**But** making a synonym between joomla and joomla3.0and another synonym between joomla and joomla1.5  (for example) => so searching for something 3.x specific my return questions which are outdated and not relevant (like the 1.5 release).

Maybe somebody with more experience in tag-synonyms can share some experiences.

Comment: I am on the practical side. Getting mix between 3.x and 1.5 in the search is not such a big deal imho, but visibility of questions and answers is important

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it's become a pain traversing all the different tags when so many could be bundled together.

Comment: do you think we should put it all under [tag:joomla] tag, or per series?

Answer (score 0):

As we will have (hopefully) our own distribution, i would recommend "version only" tags like ubuntu does. So if the question is version related just add "2.5" or "3.0" as tag.

Comment: For all: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla ;)